# Discord.py focusing back on a PM conversation

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there a way to focus on PMs with someone (way to switch where the bot is looking at to PMs with someone).

I'm trying to code something where the bot recognizes an image the person sends and returns what it saw in the image. I'm using my own computer for this so the recognizer needs to see the chat to recognize image. How do I switch to a chat?

I can `use on_message()`, I just don't know how to go to the PMs with the author of the person.

Comment: `on_message` gives you access to the message that was sent, which will allow you access to the channel, the user, and any other data associated with the `discord.Message` object. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make my bot forward DMs sent to it to a channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65062678/how-to-make-my-bot-forward-dms-sent-to-it-to-a-channel)